# method that allows remote SSH server to backup files from a webhost given only SFTP credentials?

Tags: ssh, backup, sftp

I do not know what to search on Google to actually lead me to the right answer. When I tried it says `rsync` or `scp` but I do not think this will solve my problem because for obvious reason SFTP-only credential will not allow you to install both unix program (it does not have command line).

My website and its files are all hosted to a `shared web host` meaning the only way to access the files are via `SFTP credential` they gave me.

I have a unix VPS that has `SSH credentials` at which I want to be a backup storage.

Is there a command/method at which my unix VPS will log in the SFTP credentials of my webhost and then backup all the files or directory I want?

Hope somebody knows how to do this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scp -r user@host:/path/to/dir /local/dir
```

Comment: do you know how to escape spaces? I cannot make this escape `scp -r user@remotehost:"/files/r/New\ Folder/" '/var/www/html/New Folder'`